# php json_encode() output changes based on the array indices

Tags: php, json

I was trying to get some values from MySQL database and when converting into JSON array using json_encode() I got a JSON object , after a while I found out that the indices was the root cause of the problem

here's the example I mentioned

```
<?php
$array = array(0=>"zero",2=>"two");
$another_array=array(0=>"zero",1=>"one");

print_r(json_encode($array)); // output: {"0":"zero","2":"two"}
print_r(json_encode($another_array)); //output: ["zero","one"]
?>
```

so what's the reason for that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `array(0=>"zero",1=>"one")` is the same as `array("zero", "one")` and the JSON encoder assumes the latter is a list (since that's how PHP does lists) and has no way to tell the former from the latter.

If you want to force `json_encode` to treat all arrays as objects, pass [`JSON_FORCE_OBJECT`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php) as the second argument:

```
json_encode(array(0=>"zero",1=>"one"), JSON_FORCE_OBJECT)
// {"0":"zero","1":"one"}
```

If you always want a json list instead, get rid of the keys (e.g. using [`array_values()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)) before encoding.

Comment: and what about `array(0=>"zero",2=>"two")` ?

Comment: That doesn't have contiguous-counting-up-from-zero indices, and thus gets treated as an object no matter what because it can't be a list.